# Laravel send email, configuration and send script

Tags: php, laravel, email

I have a problem with my laravel email client.
I need to send email by click button.

my code:
.env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.somedomain.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=test@somedomain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=123456
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

I think it is good configuration, of course i'm using my domain :)

next in controller I have code like this:

```
Mail::send('home', array('firstname' => "fname"), function($message){
$message->to("testsend@somedomain.com")->subject('Welcome to the Laravel');
});
```

Website is open normally but email not send

Comment: Seems to be Ok. Messages may ending up into SPAM folder if you haven't set up SPF/DKIM correctly on your domain DNS configuration.

Comment: okey, thanks :) I check everything again. My Setup is the same on direct admin report and thunderbird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Gmail account

My account > Sign In And Security > Sign In to google, enable two step verification

- http://i.prntscr.com/7c849cb520e84f02b39216f3662590bc.png
- http://i.prntscr.com/cc52e9b8e7c2472496f1e2d2ec8185f8.png

Create One App and generate password

- http://i.prntscr.com/b38cdca0724446d8a53b22dfa5f43ee6.png

In your .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=apppassword // this is created from gmail app password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

And Then run `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: Sorry My Screen shot is not displaying here. but let me know if any problem in that.