# Sending queue email in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, email, laravel-5

I have set up my laravel configuration for sending email using queue. have make my queue table (jobs), and migrate the database then I have config my .env file like this :

```
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=**database**

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_USERNAME=**myemail@astrnt.co**
MAIL_PASSWORD=**maypasseheh**
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Database config in my queue.php :

```
'database' => [
    'driver' => 'database',
    'table' => 'jobs',
    'queue' => 'default',
    'expire' => 60,
],
```

Then in my route, I have made a route like this :

```
Route::get('sendqueue/mail',function()
{
    Mail::later(5,'view_email', ['msg' => 'Hisoka data from email queue...'], function($message)
        {
            $message->to('hyosoka187@gmail.com','From Maryadi_astronaut')->subject('test email');
        });

    return 'From route....';
});
```

Then I run `php artisan queue:listen`, but the mail just pushed to database but never sent to my email. In my database there are some attempt that has been done by laravel :
[image]

Am I missing some configurations here...???
Thanks in advance.. :)

Note:
I'm running this laravel using xampp in windows 7

Somebody Heeeelp.... :')

This is the log file :

```
[internal function]: Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->fire()
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\TestQueue2\queuelagi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(507): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\TestQueue2\queuelagi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php(169): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\TestQueue2\queuelagi\vendor\symfony\console\Command\Command.php(256): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#16 C:\xampp\htdocs\TestQueue2\queuelagi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php(155): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#17 C:\xampp\htdocs\TestQueue2\queuelagi\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(794): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#18 C:\xampp\htdocs\TestQueue2\queuelagi\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(186): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#19 C:\xampp\htdocs\TestQueue2\queuelagi\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(117): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#20 C:\xampp\htdocs\TestQueue2\queuelagi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(107): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#21 C:\xampp\htdocs\TestQueue2\queuelagi\artisan(35): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#22 {main}
```

Comment: What does the log say? It's located in storage/log directory. For cleaner look you can delete the log file and then try to make an attempt to send the mail, so it will contain only related messages. For debugging mail you can use services like https://mailtrap.io/, it acts like a mail server, but captures all the mail without actually sending to the recipients.

Comment: I have put the log file on question Mr. @Mikhail Zhuravlev.... and btw... After execute queue:work then queue:listen, theere are somenotification that the queue email has been sent. Then I check the queue database {job db}, sure it's data has been reduced... But until now the sent email never reach me...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38057234/laravel-send-email-configuration-and-send-script/38184222#38184222

Might be useful for you..

Comment: From the link your provide mr.@krunal nerikar.... It said that I need to config my cache... after doing php artisan config:cache. THen I run php artisan queue:listen, I got this error :
PHP FATAL ERROR: Uncaught reflectionException: CLass log does not exiist in C:\xampp\..\...\... 

php artisan serve can't run too with the same error... mmmm..... What's happening ....?? :)

Comment: I suddently can't run php artisan....