# Laravel 5.2 Mail cannot be sent outside domain

Tags: laravel-5, swiftmailer, exchange-server-2010

So when I try to send mails with Laravel's mail facade, I can only send within our company domain, when trying to send E-mails to either gmail or outlook, the mail never gets deliviered, but if I use outlook, the mail is delivered instantly.

I have turned everything upside down to figure out what it can be, but I cant find anything that cause this issue, not even a single trace of my app sending "non-internal" mails in the exchange logs.

Our company uses an Exchange 2003 server, I have checked the logs, no trace of (Out of company) mails are there

Im on a 20 hour streak, sorry for any confusion

/Tarre

Comment: please look into this may be it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38057234/laravel-send-email-configuration-and-send-script

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that our Exchange SMTP relay didnt have the correct connectors and configuration.

To use exchange with SMTP.

1. Add a Connector bridge between your Exchange server and the Virtual SMTP server.
2. Configure "trusted" IP's.

Everything is done in the Exchange Server Management part.